# Next.js not able to pre-render error page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I recently started to use Next.JS on a new project and it's working fine but I can't figure out how to keep my layout state active on client side when I throw a 404 error after clicking on a wrong link.

Thanks to [Adam's Wathan article](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/), I'm able to share my state between different pages :

On home page

[image]

On "about" page

[image]

But if i click on "error", it will render the _error.tsx without preserving data i wrote in the input.
[image]

This page seems to render the whole app tree on server side, despite the fact I provide the same layout. Is there anyway to prefetch this page, just like a regular one and avoid to lose some information without using a solution like Redux ? I'm note quite familiar with it and it seems a bit too much in this case.

Here is my code:
pages/_error.tsx

```
import { getLayout } from "../components/layout/mainLayout"
import { withTranslation } from "../i18n";
import { FlexDirectionProperty } from "csstype";

const imgStyle = {
  maxWidth: "100%",
  maxHeight: "100%"
};

const figureStyle = {
  height: "80vh",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  flexDirection: "column" as FlexDirectionProperty
};

const CustomError: any = ({ status, t }: any) => (
  <>
    <figure style={figureStyle}>
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Statut:{t('WELCOME')}</h1>
      </figcaption>
      <img
        alt="Showing a properly cat according the status code"
        src={`https://http.cat/${status}`}
        style={imgStyle}
      />
    </figure>
  </>
)

CustomError.getLayout = getLayout;

CustomError.getInitialProps = async ({ res, err }: any) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : null

  return {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    namespacesRequired: ["common"]
  }
};

export default withTranslation('common')(CustomError)
```

components/layout/header.tsx

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { withTranslation, i18n } from "../../i18n";
import { capitalize } from "../../helpers/utils";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import { useState } from "react";

const loadStamp = +new Date();

const Header: any = ({ t }: any) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState("home");

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar fixed="top" bg="light">
        <Nav className="mr-auto" activeKey={active}>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Link href="/">
              <Navbar.Brand onClick={() => setActive("home")} href="/">Random Project</Navbar.Brand>
            </Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          ...
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    </>);
};

export default withTranslation("common")(Header);
```

components/layout/mainLayout.tsx

```
import Header from "./header";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../../public/stylesheets/style.scss";

type LayoutProps = {
  title?: string;
  children: any;
};

const Layout: React.FunctionComponent<LayoutProps> = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <main role="main" className="main">
      {children}
    </main>
  </>
);

export const getLayout: any = (page: any) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>

export default Layout
```

And my _app.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import { appWithTranslation } from '../i18n'

class MyApp extends App<any> {

    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
        const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page: any) => page)

        return (
            <>
                {getLayout(
                    <Component {...pageProps}></Component>
                )}
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp)
```